# Passing more than one parameters in route messes up my view

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner to laravel. When I pass more than one parameter through the route my view gets messed up. For example when my route is {{URL/product}}. It is ok, but when try it the other way i.e {{URL/product/anything}}, the view is messed up.
[This is the correct view[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9z8t.png)

These are my routes :

(Working)
`Route::get('/addproduct' , 'AdminController@add_product')->name('add_product');`[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9z8t.png)

(not working)

`Route::get('/add/product' , 'AdminController@add_product')->name('add_product');`[This one is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zS7f.png)

I haven't changed anything but my web.php file.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... perhaps you could show your route definitions as it is not fully clear what you are trying to imply is happening

Comment: Sure kindly wait a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because of how you are linking to your assets. You are most likely using relative URLs. Try using one of the URL helpers to generate absolute URLs for you.

```
href="{{ asset('css/somefile.css') }}"
```

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Helpers - URLs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers) `asset`

Comment: I was keeping my assets in the public file and not in resources/assets. Can that be the problem? Currently the linking is like {{"css/somefile.css"}}

Comment: they need to be in the `public` folder to have access to them, `asset` is just a name of this helper it isn't related to the 'assets' folder

Comment: Mate, the solution was exactly what you said. As soon as I added asset helper, it was good. Thanks a lot, genius.